# Application is working in Debug mode but not in release mode

Tags: flutter

The release mode of the application is not able to fetch the data from the url and hence the screen just shows 'loading...'

I am using `package:http/http.dart` package to fetch the data.

Here's how my `State` class looks like :

```
class HomeState extends State<Home>{

      Future<List<Coin>> getCoinList() async {
        var url = '<some_url>';
        var response = await http.get(url);
        var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
        //iterate through jsonData, create a list and return
      }

      Future<void> updateData() async{
        setState((){});
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return RefreshIndicator(child: FutureBuilder(
            future: getCoinList(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.data == null) {
                return Center(
                  child: Container(
                    child: Text("Loading..."),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                      String sign = '-';
                      MaterialColor signColor = Colors.red;
                      if(double.parse(snapshot.data[position].percent_change_1h) > 0.0){
                        sign = '+';
                        signColor = Colors.green;
                      }
                      return Card(
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(snapshot.data[position].name,style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                          subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[position].price_usd,style: TextStyle(color: signColor),),
                          trailing: Text(sign+snapshot.data[position].percent_change_1h+"%",style: TextStyle(color: signColor),),
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              }
            }), onRefresh: updateData);
      }
    }
```

Please explain in detail what's wrong with the code and how to fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`getCoinList()` returns the updated data, but you actually need to set the state to use that new data using something like

```
setState () {
coindata = getCoinList();
}
```

If you don't update the state object, the list will not be rebuilt.